# Check that string matches mask format without regex

Tags: android, kotlin

I have mask from backend, for example this mask can be like this: `"99-99-99"` where 9 - any integer value

How I can check that entered by user string matches with this mask?

Backend doesn't send regex so I can't use it

Comment: Do you have a self defined pattern between the app and the backend? If it is the situation, you can convert the pattern to a regex. If there is any other problem, please be specific and clear it with an example

Comment: It can be any pattern, for example for one object it will be "99-99-99", for another one "99 99-999 : 99". on the client side I don't know anything about this mask. Do you mean that I can convert pattern to regex by code? If yes, could you show me how can I do it?

Comment: So your backend supplies you some pseudo-regex, like "99-99-99", instead of an actual regex, such as  `^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$`? You're asking how to convert this pseudo-regex into regex you can use? What are the rules for this pattern you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your pattern to a regex and use it. Because your pattern is not a standard pattern, you should convert it based on your needs. For example, you can check your mentioned pattern with a code like this :

```
"your pattern".replace("9", "\\d").toRegex().matches("your input")
```